# how to add an id to an inner div in an elementor widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

As you know elementor widgets contain several html elements like div. Some of these elements have IDs and some not. How can I set ID to those with no ID to customize that specific part inside widget?

Elementor itself provides setting id to the widget itself. I don't mean that.